# Model updates trigger "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed" error when using Map in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, publish-subscribe, xcode14

I am using the code below to do the following.

1. Create a new item every 5 seconds and append it to the model
2. Display a list of items in the listView
3. Display a map of the items in the mapView

If I am in the listView, the list gets properly updated every 5 seconds with the new item. No error message.
If I am in the mapView, the map also gets updated (a new marker every 5 seconds), but I get error "[SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior."
Since list and map both display the same model data, I wonder why map complains and list does not. The actual model update is on the main actor, so why is it complaining.

Any idea?

```
//Model
struct TestApp1Model {
    struct TestItem: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
    }

    var items = [TestItem]()
}

// ViewModel
class TestApp1ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var model = TestApp1Model()
    private var timer:Timer?
 
    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { _ in
            Task { @MainActor in
                self.addItem()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var items:[TestApp1Model.TestItem] {
        model.items
    }
    
    @MainActor func addItem () {
        let name = "Item " + model.items.count.description
        let latitude = Double.random(in: 45...55)
        let longitude = Double.random(in: 5...11)
        model.items.append(TestApp1Model.TestItem(name: name, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
    }
}

// View
struct TestApp1View: View {
    @StateObject var testVM = TestApp1ViewModel()
    @State var region:MKCoordinateRegion
    
    init() {
        self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50, longitude: 8), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 6))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            listView
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                    Text("List")
                }
                .backgroundStyle(Color.white)
            mapView
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "map")
                    Text("Map")
                }
                .backgroundStyle(Color.white)
        }
    }
    
    var listView: some View {
        VStack {
            List (testVM.items) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item.name)
                    Text(item.latitude.description)
                    Text(item.longitude.description)
               }
            }
        }
    }

    var mapView: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true,annotationItems: testVM.items) {item in
            MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: item.latitude, longitude: item.longitude)) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should publish your array of items, not the model.

```
struct TestItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [TestItem]()
    private var timer: Timer?

    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { _ in
            Task { @MainActor in
                self.addItem()
            }
        }
    }

    @MainActor func addItem () {
        let name = "Item " + items.count.description
        let latitude = Double.random(in: 45...55)
        let longitude = Double.random(in: 5...11)
        items.append(TestItem(name: name, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
    }
}
```

Now your views will update each time a new item is added.

Comment: My views do update. @Published will trigger an update each time anything within the model changes. The issue is not that the views do not update, but that the update in the mapView creates the above error message.
I have however changed the code as per your suggestion and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Do you have more code than this? I'm not getting that error at all.

Comment: This is the whole project (except imports and comments). The full project is here: [link](https://github.com/devkonlinenet/TestApp1).
The error comes up at run-time, not compile-time. I am using Xcode 14, development target is IOS 16.0.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across similar issues with SwiftUI's Map to the point where I'm convinced it's a bug.  In the cases I've encountered the warning message appears once for each annotation on the map, even when the annotations aren't changing but the view is being redrawn due to a change in a published property.  I'm giving up on SwiftUI's Map.  Going back to MKMapView - better support and all these warnings go away.

Comment: In my use case of using `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` I get the same "warning" but UI-wise it works perfectly. I have submitted and feedback/issue report to SwiftUI and will update you here if I get a response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with Map(). It started appearing with Xcode 14. Other people see this run-time warning in other scenarios. For now, I assume it's a bug that will be fixed in future Xcode updates.

See: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711899

And: https://www.donnywals.com/xcode-14-publishing-changes-from-within-view-updates-is-not-allowed-this-will-cause-undefined-behavior/

Comment: It is either a bug or a change in the way we have to use SwiftUI/Combine that has not been communicated well. I tested Xcode 14.1 beta 3 and it has the same issue. I tested some code from one of Paul Hudson's Hacking with Swift tutorials and it too runs into that issue. I consider Paul a much better programmer and he usually is on top of things, so that makes me think it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Add a manual binding with its setter working in the main thread.

This code was producing the same warning:

```
struct AreaMap: View {
    @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}
```

Where `region` was passed in the initializer of `AreaMap` from its parent view.

And this resolved the issue for me:

```
struct AreaMap: View {
    @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    var body: some View {
        let binding = Binding(
            get: { self.region },
            set: { newValue in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.region = newValue
                }
            }
        )
        return Map(coordinateRegion: binding)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but the result remains the same. It is not the region parameter that causes the issue, but the items I use for the annotations (which indeed is changed every couple of seconds).

Comment: @Mike
Did you make sure the binding is created inside `body` property not outside it?

Comment: @Tony your code works fine, but I've noticed that if I try to add annotationItems to the AreaMap, the "purple warnings" come back. Any advice on how to add annotations to your working code, above? Thanks. Also - do you think this is a bug or a legitimate change in the way SwiftUI will work from now on.

Comment: I create the binding inside the body as you do, but as mentioned earlier, it does not seem to be the region that is the issue, but the annotation items. I tried to use a similar binding for the annotation items, but it did not help. Even if it would work, it would still be a strange workaround. I still think it is some sort of bug, especially since only the map is affected. The same items displayed as a standard list does not trigger purple warnings, although the mechanism is exactly the same.

Comment: @Gallaugher 
Putting the binding inside `body` looks very bad to me so I think it is a bug. I belive Apple will either fix it or communicate the correct way to deal with it.